# Inaccessible i18n messages and script from grails binary plugin

Tags: java, grails, plugins, jar, grails-plugin

I've created custom grails plugin, which works fine when using inline. But now I need to use it in few other apps, so I thought that I package it into *.jar file by running

```
grails package-plugin --binary
```

After putting the *.jar file into an app's lib directory the plugin is loading, but I can't execute plugin's script (I looked into the jar and all plugin scripts are included). The script isn't also listed in the "grails help" output

The same problem is with i18n messages - on rendered views there are displayed messages keys instead of translations :(

Plugin and app are running under grails 2.3.5

Does anybody had similar problem and found a solution?